# Bing Maps info box not displayed - setMap is not a function error on console

Tags: javascript, maps, bing-maps, bing-api

My bing maps would not load the info box.
I have an array that creates pushpins for the locations rendered and below is the code that I use.
I have added the console message for the display to check if it is being called properly which it does. I was wondering if offset/anchor has got something to do with not having infobox not being displayed. Can someone help me here?

```
    var arrPins = [];
var arrPinCenter = [];
//Generating Pins for multiple locations with Lat,Long
for (var locNum = 0; locNum <= arrLocInfoRec.length - 1; locNum++) {
    try {
           arrLLAdder = arrLocInfoRec[locNum].split("`");
           if (arrLLAdder.length >= 13) {
                 arrPinCenter[locNum] = new Microsoft.Maps.Location(parseFloat(arrLLAdder[11]), parseFloat(arrLLAdder[12]));
                 arrPinCenter[locNum] = new Microsoft.Maps.Location(parseFloat(arrLLAdder[11]), parseFloat(arrLLAdder[12]));
                 arrPins[locNum] = new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(
                  arrPinCenter[locNum], {                                                                                                
                 text: arrLLAdder[8] ,                                                                                                                                                                icon: 'https://www.bingmapsportal.com/Content/images/poi_custom.png',                                                                                                    anchor: new Microsoft.Maps.Point(12, 39) 
                                                                                    }
 var adder = arrLLAdder[2] + '\r\n' + arrLLAdder[4] + '\r\n' + arrLLAdder[6] + arrLLAdder[9] + "\r\n" + arrLLAdder[1]
     // Create the infobox for the pushpin
 arrPinInfobox[locNum] = new Microsoft.Maps.Infobox(arrPins[locNum].getLocation(),
      {   width: 350,
          height: 100,
          title: arrLLAdder[5],
          description: adder,
          offset: new Microsoft.Maps.Point(-3,13)`enter code here`
        });
 // Add handler for the pushpin click event.
 Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(arrPins[locNum], 'click', displayInfobox);
    }

 else {
   console.log("Invalid Data: arrLocInfoRec[" + locNum + "] = \"" + arrLocInfoRec[locNum] + "\"");
                        }`enter code here`
                    } catch (e) {
                        console.log(e.message + "\r\n" + arrLocInfoRec[locNum]);
                    }
                }
// Hide the infobox when the map is moved.
// Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(map, 'viewchange', hideInfobox);    
// Add the Push Pins and InfoBox to the map all at once

       if(arrPins.length > 0) {
                  map.entities.push(arrPins); //[locNum]
                  arrPinInfobox.setMap(map);

//I get a console error here for the setMap function 
// see error below
                    //map.entities.push(arrPinInfobox);
                    //map.entities.push(InfoBoxEntity);
                }


            }
```

> Uncaught TypeError: arrPinInfobox.setMap is not a function at GetMap
>   (68A611D186DE4DC991773CAED323DA31.ashx:135)  at
>   Object.Microsoft.Maps.notifyMapReadyForBootstrap
>   (www.bing.com/mapspreview/sdk/mapcontrol?branch=release&callback=GetMap:14)
>   at
>   www.bing.com/rms/SDKPlugin/jc,nj/9ac8b1b9/4153aba0.js?//bu=rms+answers+MapsSD…leLayer*MapsTilePrimer*SDKMap*PointCompression*SDKPluginEnd*AnonymousEnd:1
>   at
>   www.bing.com/rms/SDKPlugin/jc,nj/9ac8b1b9/4153aba0.js?//bu=rms+answers+MapsSD…//leLayer*MapsTilePrimer*SDKMap*PointCompression*SDKPluginEnd*AnonymousEnd:1

I use the below code to display the infobox

```
            function displayInfobox(e) {
                   //map.entities.push(arrPinInfobox);
                console.log("DisplayBox");
                for(var i in arrPinInfobox)
                    arrPinInfobox[i].setOptions({ visible: true });
                arrPinInfobox[parseInt(e.target.getText()) - 1].setOptions({ visible: true });
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add some break points to your code and step through it. Your code is a bit messy but it looks like it is possible that by the time you get to the setMap line of code, the infobox was never created as it is created inside of a try statement and is possible it never got created.

That said, I highly recommend using a single infobox for better performance. Take a look at this code sample: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt750274.aspx